# Consulta ao banco de dados em PHP com WHERE não retorna valor

Tags: php, html, mysql

A variável de consulta que uso pra consultar a posição no banco de dados é a `$fornecedor` que recebe `$_POST['fornecedor']` vindo de outra página, porém a consulta não retorna valores só fica em branco, quando uso a função `mysqli_errno()` ela retorna **0**. A conexão com o banco de dados está configurada na função `infoConnect()` que está sendo importada no include, a conexão está sendo feita normalmente. Quando faço a consulta sem o WHERE na query somente usando o SELECT e o FROM consigo retorno porém esse filtro WHERE é necessário para o funcionamento correto do sistema, enfim, não estou conseguindo visualizar o erro.

```
<?php

    include "../requeriments/connect_info.php";

    $fornecedor = $_POST['fornecedor'];
    echo("<br>");
    echo($fornecedor); /*Teste para ver se variável está definida*/
        
    $query = " SELECT id, nome, tipo, capacidade, custo, telefone, urlthumb FROM fornecedores WHERE nome = '$fornecedor' ";
    $result = mysqli_query(infoConnect(), $query) or die("Erro na consulta.");

    while($row_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    
?>

    <form method="POST" action="alter_provider.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
    <label for="id" id="formColum_1">Id:</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="<?php echo(($row_result['id'])); ?>" id="formColumn_2" name="id" disabled><br>

    <label for="nome" id="formColum_1">Fornecedor:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo(utf8_encode($row_result['nome'])); ?>" id="formColumn_2" name="nome" ><br>

    <label for="tipo" id="formColum_1">Tipo:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo(utf8_encode($row_result['tipo'])); ?>" id="formColumn_2" name="tipo" ><br>

    <label for="capacidade" id="formColum_1">Capacidade:</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="<?php echo($row_result['capacidade']); ?>" id="formColumn_2" name="capacidade" ><br>

    <label for="custo" id="formColum_1">Custo:</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="<?php echo($row_result['custo']); ?>" id="formColumn_2" name="custo" ><br>

    <label for="telefone" id="formColum_1">Telefone:</label>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="<?php echo($row_result['telefone']); ?>" id="formColumn_2" name="telefone" ><br>

    <label for="urlthumb" id="formColum_1">Imagem:</label>
    <input type="file" id="formColumn_2" name="urlthumb" accept="image/jpeg, image/png"><br><br>
            
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>


    </form>

<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem ter o script de criação do DB e os dados nenhuma resposta poderá ser 100% acertiva, mas dado que o script funciona sem o `where` e com o `where` não tem qualquer retorno e também não há erros, o mais provável é que a query correu com sucesso mas não houve mesmo qualquer resultado encontrado pelo DB.

Olhando a sua query, você está buscando um fornecedor com o nome `$fornecedor`. Deverá ser necessário alterar a query para fazer a interpolação de textos:

```php
$query = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, capacidade, custo, telefone, urlthumb FROM fornecedores WHERE nome = '". $fornecedor ."'";
```

Ainda assim, como o seu filtro é por uma coluna chamada `nome` o mais provável é que seja do tipo "texto". Neste caso poderá ser problemas com casing ou collation do DB/tabela/coluna. Confirme que o nome na base de dados é exatamente igual ao nome recebido no post (mesmo maiúsculas e minúsculas) e altere o `where` para usar `LIKE` no lugar do `=`.

```sql
(...) FROM fornecedores WHERE nome LIKE '". $fornecedor ."'";
```

Por fim, gostava de acrescentar que esse tipo de query NUNCA deve ser feita, pois permite qualquer pessoa ter acesso à base de dados por meio de SQL injection. Entretanto esse já seria outro tema.

Answer (score 0):

Já que o retorno acontece sem o `where` e sua variavel esta passando o valor, o que posso pensar é na forma que foi inserida a variavel no sql, para testar a fundo dê um `echo($query)` e veja como o valor está sendo inserido no seu sql. Teste concatenar sua variavel assim.

```
$query = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, capacidade, custo, telefone, urlthumb FROM fornecedores WHERE nome = '".$fornecedor."'";
```

Ou

```
$query = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, capacidade, custo, telefone, urlthumb FROM fornecedores WHERE nome = '{$fornecedor}' ";
```