# While não exibe se eu usar o get id?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, while, get

Alguém me ajuda a entender o porque esse código não ta conseguindo exibir o genero do banco?

```
 <div class="first_info">
      <?php
       $vide = $_GET['i'];  
include "core/home/database.php";
$consultaGe = "SELECT * FROM generos WHERE id='$vide'";
$conGenre = $mysqli->query($consultaGe) or die (@mysqli_error());  

?>
      <strong>Generos:</strong>
    <?php while($gene = $conGenre->fetch_array()){ ?>
      <div>
         <h5 class="cop_genre" value="<?php echo $gene['id'];?>"><?php echo $gene['genre']; ?></h5>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Se eu tiro o `WHERE id='$vide'` ai ele exibe, mas ele exibe todos os generos, e não somente o dele. O que está errado ai?

A estrutura da tabela generos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Consulta ao banco de dados em PHP com WHERE não retorna valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/489833/consulta-ao-banco-de-dados-em-php-com-where-n%c3%a3o-retorna-valor)

Comment: Não concatene os valores direto na query, pois isso deixa a aplicação vulnerável a ataques de SQL injection. Leia mais sobre o assunto aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9734/112052

Comment: o while esta engolindo o h5 e não sei o porque

Comment: Apenas para esclarecer, na URL chamada você está incluindo o parâmetro "i"? Por exemplo `https://example.com/index.php?i=generodesejado`.

Comment: sim ele esta, tanto que todo o resto funciona, a unica coisa é que ele pega o "i" de tudo do filme. Não somente do genero

Comment: Tipo, ele não esta pegando o gênero do banco dos gêneros e sim o numero do gênero que esta no banco do filme, acho que isso pode estar sendo o problema, mas ainda não sei como resolver, por isso que se eu colocar só `$v['genre'];` ele aparece o numero do genero e não o nome dele, dai tentei esse código ai em cima, mas sem sucesso, ele não mostra o nome.

Comment: Poderia colocar a estrutura da tabela `generos`?

Comment: claro posso sim

Comment: `WHERE id='$vide'`, se `$vide` é 1, a query será `id='1'`, mas a coluna `id` é do tipo INT, não precisa as aspas. Deveria ser `id=$vide` (mas melhor que isso seria se você usasse o `prepare` do MySQLi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinicius,
Como quando você retira a condição `WHERE id='$vide'` são exibidos todos os gêneros acredito que o "problema" está no parâmetro `i`.

Pelos seus comentários e pelo nome da variável (`$vide`) acredito que você está passando o `id` do vídeo e não do gênero. Se for isso mesmo você precisa alterar sua consulta para que você busque o id do gênero dentro da tabela de vídeos (em uma subconsulta) e usar na consulta do gênero.

Ficaria algo assim (não sei como é sua tabela de vídeos):

```
$consultaGe = "SELECT * FROM generos WHERE id=(SELECT id_genero FROM videos WHERE id='$vide')";
```

**Edit:** Atente ao comentário do @hkotsubo e procure formas de melhorar a segurança do seu aplicativo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, no caso sim, o i estava pagando o do vídeo e não somente do gênero, mas com a subconsulta funcionou perfeitamente. Em relação a segurança estou pesquisando meios de aprimorar esta parte no meu código. Mas obrigado ajudou muito